# How do I make mysite.com/comingsoon WordPress to become my main website's WordPress?

Tags: customization, options

I joined Bluehost and then I can create some WordPress, except if it is the button "Start Designing", I cannot make it the top level, root of the website.

If I want to add to top level website, I have to use "No thanks, go to WordPress".

So I created a `/comingsoon` instead, and that will let me choose some designs.

The tech support person said, I can just

```
cd ~/public_html
cp -R comingsoon/* .
rm index.html.  # if any
```

But that's a really low level operation.  It didn't work initially and he said he had to do something related to Weebly. How does it work?  How do I make the `mysite.com/comingsoon` content to become `mysite.com` ?

Comment: What's at the top level at the moment, another WordPress? You could just switch the database connection and wp-content, but I'm not sure that's any better. What he's given you doesn't look crazy, although I'd probably move the existing files out of the way rather than overwrite them like this. However it might be simplest to get the tech support person on the phone or on chat and work through this with them? Is Weebly your web host?

Comment: I don't like to do such low level stuff usually, when the whole thing is set up by a lot of scripts, and I am underneath moving the files around using Bash... talk to them... I told them at one point I don't have the user name and password for WordPress admin or something, and they told me, "Don't worry. Just type them in and you should be able to log in."

Answer (score 0):

You can update the default front page via WordPress CMS.

On the main dashboard, navigate to the ‘Settings’, then ‘Reading’ menu.  Change ‘Front Page Displays to ‘A Static Page (select below). Then select the page using the drop down which you require to be your front page.

Comment: I think it's a separate install of WordPress though, or maybe only the one install but in a different folder.